# Tense of the word

Tags: word-choice, tense

The manager ____(feel) the need to ___(train) his team on e-mail etiquette since last may.

Will it be felt or feels?.. and why?

Comment: Either is fine. It depends entirely on whether what described took place in the past or takes place in the present.

Answer (score 1):

> The manager **has felt** the need to train his team on e-mail etiquette since last **M**ay.

<sup>(bold = change)</sup>

So, this would be an example of **present perfect tense** since we're talking about *last May*. From Grammarly blog, this is what present perfect tense is:

> The present perfect tense refers to an action or state that either occurred at an indefinite time in the past (e.g., we have talked before) or began in the past and continued to the present time (e.g., he has grown impatient over the last hour). This tense is formed by have/has + the past participle.

However, no matter what tense you are talking about, *to train* will always remain the same because it is an **infinitive** form of a verb. Here's the Google Definition of an *infinitive*:

> the basic form of a verb, without an inflection binding it to a particular subject or tense (e.g. see in we came to see, let him see ).

So, you see, it's not tense-specific.